# How can I select the monitor where I want to open my application?

Tags: delphi, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Start program on a second monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206400/start-program-on-a-second-monitor)

I have two monitor a monitor connected to my laptop. How can I choose the monitor where my application will show?

Also how can I detect how many monitor do I have connected so that I can select one ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate and related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206400/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Screen` object.

**Getting the monitor count**

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Screen.MonitorCount))
```

**Getting monitor details**

```
Screen.Monitors[i].Left (integer)
                  .Top (integer)
                  .Width (integer)
                  .Height (integer)
                  .BoundsRect (TRect)
                  .WorkareaRect (TRect)
                  .Primary (boolean)
```

where i is the index of the monitor, that is, i = 0, 1, ..., `Screen.MonitorCount - 1`.

So, for instance, to make the form occupy the entire ith monitor, use

```
BoundsRect := Screen.Monitors[i].BoundsRect; // or you could make the rect smaller
WindowState := wsMaximized; // possibly
```

Comment: Of course, for very simply situations, setting the `DefaultMonitor` property might be enough for ones needs.