# How to specify the monitor for Puppeteer launch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have two monitors and every time I run `puppeteer.launch()` in non-headless mode, it sent the browser to the monitor on left.  It is annoying as left monitor is my main monitor where I write code with.  Can I set a parameter so that it'll send browser to my right monitor?  I've search its API but couldn't find such parameter.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27957436/2625560

Comment: Brilliant!!!  It worked!  For reference, the exact syntax is `let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--window-size=1920,1080", "--window-position=1921,0"]
  })`